# Trying to save multiple files in Django 2 Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have read the various posts on saving multiple files using the django 2 admin, but I still can't get it to work.

My model:

```
class Document(Model):
    document_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document_state = models.IntegerField(choices=DOCUMENT_STATE, default=PRIVATE, verbose_name="state")
    documentType_id = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="document type", )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")
    storage_file_name = models.FileField('File name', upload_to=unique_file_path)
    thumb_storage = models.FileField(editable=False,)
    original_file_name = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=200)
    computed_sha256 = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=64)
```

I create my own field in the Document admin, so I added the 'multiple' keyword to the field. The field for storage_file_name looks like this in the admin create document page:

```
<label class="required" for="id_storage_file_name">File name:</label>
    <input type="file" name="storage_file_name" multiple required id="id_storage_file_name" />
```

I have this in save_model in the DocumentAdmin class:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        logger.debug("save_model START")
        logger.debug("obj=%s, change=%s" % (obj, change))
        if (form.is_valid()):
            logger.debug("\tvalid form")
            logger.debug("form.cleaned_data=%s",form.cleaned_data)
            obj.metadata = form.cleaned_data['metadata']
        logger.debug("files=%s" % request.FILES.getlist('storage_file_name'))
        files = request.FILES.getlist('storage_file_name')
        for f in files:
            logger.debug("storing file=%s" % f)
            obj.storage_file_name = f
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        logger.debug("save_model END")
```

files has the right list of files I want to upload. But I can't seem to save more than the last item in the list of files. I don't get any error messages; just the first n images in the list if files selected are not uploaded.

I would rather not include one of the many django-multiple-file-upload apps in my app if I can avoid it. I would rather understand what I am doing wrong and fix it!

Thanks!

Mark

PS After trying different approaches, this finally works. Note there is no call to super.save_model, which seems to be an issue based on the django docs.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    logger.debug("save_model START")
    logger.debug("obj=%s, change=%s" % (obj, change))
    if (form.is_valid()):
        logger.debug("\tvalid form")
        logger.debug("form.cleaned_data=%s",form.cleaned_data)
        logger.debug("files=%s" % request.FILES.getlist('storage_file_name'))
        files = request.FILES.getlist('storage_file_name')
        for f in files:
            logger.debug("storing file=%s" % f)
            obj2 = Document()
            obj2.storage_file_name = f
            obj2.metadata = form.cleaned_data['metadata']
            obj2.document_state = form.cleaned_data['document_state']
            obj2.documentType_id = form.cleaned_data['documentType_id']
            obj2.save()
    logger.debug("save_model END")
```

The fields metadata, document_state, and documentType_id were all in the form.cleaned_data dictionary.

Is this the preferred way to upload multiple files?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

In the method `save_model` you have the obj parameter which is the object being save/change from the change page of django admin.

You on the other hand tried to save multiple objects of the model. So in the for loop the same object was being passed to the `super` call and was getting updated for the other images.

As a result you saw only the last image being saved to the database. There was nothing wrong with the `super` call.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    ...
    for f in files:
        logger.debug("storing file=%s" % f)
        # same object getting updated.
        obj.storage_file_name = f
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    logger.debug("save_model END")
```

So you have to create a new object everytime in the for loop and then save it.

Hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: OK. Should I have used super().save_model(request, obj2, form, change) in the code in my PS above, instead of obj2.save? I looked at the source for save_model, and all it does is obj.save().

Comment: Since you are saving multiple objects at once contrary to the regular flow, it is better to use your custom save_model, which you have already done.